# Ruby on Rails, upload and save image via JSON using polymorphic relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, paperclip

I have 2 models Post and Photo. Becouse I use photos in other models I had to make it polymorphic (it belongs to "virtual" model). 
This is the Photo model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :large => "800x1000>",:medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "150x150#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

And my Post looks like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :case
  has_many :photos, as: :imageable
  def as_json(options={})
    super(:include => :photos)
  end
end
```

And in DB in photos table i have all paperclip fields plus *imageable_id* and *imageable_type* (I use those photos in multiple models).

To set those fields in photos controller I use this:

```
def set_imageable
  params.each do |name, value|
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
      @imageable = $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

And of course this:

```
 before_action :set_imageable, only: [:create]
 def create
  @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)
  @photo.imageable = @imageable
end
```

Everything works fine, I can attach photos to multiple models but now I'm stuck with my API I want to be able to create post and attach image in one call, you think it's possible?

Maybe I should just upload image first than create post and update imageable_id and type on photos?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use relation directly?

```
@imageable.photos.create!(photo_params)
```

I should work, I think. It must create photo and automatically assign its params like imageable_id and imageable_type

Comment: This gives me: `NoMethodError (undefined method `photos' for nil:NilClass):`